# How to create an extended MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mkmapview

I have an app which uses maps on several different screens. All the maps should display the same basic information (annotations and overlays), but every instance adds different additional annotations and overlays to the map. I want to create a class, which implements the common features and behaves exactly like the `MKMapView`. How is this possible?

I've had three ideas to solve this, but none of them seems to be a good solution.

1. Subclass `MKMapView`. The problem with this approach is that the map gets the information about it's annotations and overlays from it's delegate, which should be the subclass (a view...) itself, therefore adding additional data is problematic (I can't set the delegate other than the class itself).
2. Wrap `MKMapView`. I could create an `NSObject`/`UIView` subclass which has an `MKMapView`, but either I have to proxy all of the map's methods to my class or access the map with a knowledge of the inner objects (`myMapView.mapView.xxx`...).
3. Create a delegate class (`NSObject` with `MKMapViewDelegate` functions). The delegate class could then implement the common behavior. This solution also has issues similar to the first one.

How can I solve this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and Add Map to view of that class.
Now make that class as parent class for all class where you want to add Mapview.
Provide data to parent class when you want to add annotations and overlays.

Comment: This way I should implement and proxy every MKMapView functionality if I understand you correctly.

Comment: You need to implement MKMapView methods only in parent class. And then provide data for annotations and overlays to parent class through subclass and implement method to add annotation in parent class which you need to call from child class. This way it will create new instances of mapview in each and every controller you have added and you dont need to implement MKMapView methods in all class

Comment: @gklka please check my comment

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I get what you tell me (create a view, which has the application specific functions like add waypoints from data and display boat), but I really need a generic `MKMapView` prepared with my custom annotations, because I want to use this view in multiple different places for multiple different purposes, so I have to be able to add more annotations an polylines to it.

Comment: @gklka that's what I am trying to tell you. Prepare a class which have map and add default annotation you want to add. Now make that class parent class to whatever class you want. By this way when you initialise new class having setting parent class as prepared as above then child class will have map with new instances of map and default annotation already added

Comment: Could you please show me some example code for this?